# Merge operations on historic table

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands, temporal

I would like to know if there is an existing, well-established algorithm to perform merge operations on a temporal table.

As an minimal example, say we have a table [pricedata] as such:

```
+------+------+--------+
| from | to   | price  |
+------+------+--------+
| 2008 | 2009 | 100    |
| 2009 | 2011 | 121    |
| 2011 | 2013 | 142    |
+------+------+--------+
```

(the [to] column here is supposed to be noninclusive of itself).
Now, we gets some new data to overwrite the original:

```
+------+------+--------+
| from | to   | price  |
+------+------+--------+
| 2010 | 2012 | 109    |
+------+------+--------+
```

The expected result should split and rearrange prices accordingly:

```
+------+------+--------+
| from | to   | price  |
+------+------+--------+
| 2008 | 2009 | 100    |
| 2009 | 2010 | 121    |
| 2010 | 2012 | 109    |
| 2012 | 2013 | 142    |
+------+------+--------+
```

I purposefully omit too many details, because the question is if there is already an important resource/algorithm that already does that. It feel common-need enough to be around, though my websearch has not produced anything.

Comment: Is it feasible to replace the entire temporal table with recalculated data, or is it a very large table, where maintaining existing physical rows is desirable?

Comment: FYI, a temporal table is a specific type of object is SQL Server, which stores the history of itself; this doesn't appear to be the type of object you are asking about here.

Comment: i don't know if there's any established algorithms, but to me it looks like you need to: 1. remove rows fully within the new range 2. change enddate to row where enddate is > startdate of new range 3. change startdate to row where startdate is < enddate of new range

Comment: Do you want to **store** your desired result, or store the individual rows and **present** the desired result?

Comment: @Thom A good catch, changed subject

Comment: @Andrew Ha! I want to store the expected result, which arguably proves even more a challenge.

Answer (score 1):

**Note** *This answer has been significantly revised from the original post to properly handle overlapping cases requiring a split.*

I am not sure id there is a *well-established* (well known) algorithm, but I believe the following may include the logic you are looking for.

For data with *inclusive* start dates and *exclusive* end dates, a test for overlapping dates would be `(A.FromDate < B.ToDate AND B.FromDate < A.ToDate)`.

Before inserting the new row, you can query for any existing rows that overlap the date range being inserted and adjust the existing start and end dates. These will need to be adjusted, split, or possibly even deleted to eliminate overlaps.

1. If the new range overlaps the lower end of an existing row, the `from` value of the existing row should be adjusted.
2. If the new range overlaps the upper end of an existing row, the `to` value of the existing row should be adjusted.
3. If the new range is contained entirely within the range of an existing row, that existing row will need to be duplicated and adjusted to cover the residual lower and upper ranges not superseded by the new insert.
4. If any existing rows are contained entirely within the new range being inserted, those rows may be deleted.

I have assumed that new data always supersedes existing data with an overlapping range, and that rows that have been entirely superseded may be deleted.

The following logic will handle all of the above cases:

```
-- Delete any row completely superseded by new insert
DELETE pricedata
WHERE [from] >= @InsertFrom
AND [to] <= @InsertTo 

-- Duplicate and adjust any row split by new insert, leaving lower residual
INSERT pricedata ([from], [to], price)
SELECT [from], @InsertFrom, price
FROM pricedata
WHERE [from] < @InsertFrom
AND [to] > @InsertTo 

-- Adjust original row split by new insert, leaving upper residual
UPDATE pricedata
SET [from] = @InsertTo
WHERE [from] < @InsertFrom
AND [to] > @InsertTo 

-- Trim lower end of row overlapping upper end of insert
UPDATE pricedata
SET [from] = @InsertTo
WHERE [from] >= @InsertFrom
AND [from] < @InsertTo 

-- Trim upper end of row overlapping lower end of insert
UPDATE pricedata
SET [to] = @InsertFrom
WHERE [to] > @InsertFrom
AND [to] <= @InsertTo 

-- Now that we have resolved any overlaps, we are clear to insert the new row
INSERT pricedata ([from], [to], price)
VALUES (@InsertFrom, @InsertTo, @InsertPrice)
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Hu8qhNs2) that wraps the above logic up in a stored procedure and demonstrates its operation with the OP's scenario and several other cases.

Comment: The above answer has been significantly revised from the original post to properly handle overlapping cases requiring a split.

Comment: I appreciate the effort. I already have got an answer in that such an algorithm does not exist. I will think about posting my code after it's done. It's way more complicated than this, as the combination of already existing rows and inputs should cover any case of multiple-to-multiple matches,

Comment: A solution allowing for multiple insert would be nice also.

Comment: @Charlieface - It can get complicated. I can imagine a contrived case where an existing row (range) gets trimmed at both ends and split three ways in the middle based on incoming updates. Potentially doable, if incoming rows matching (entirely contained within) an existing row are ordered, numbered, and used to generate multiple split rows. It would be a challenge. The other overlap cases should be straightforward, assuming no overlaps in the incoming data. One special case would be two input rows together eliminating an existing row by *attacking* it from both sides..